# trying to create small programs to do simple calculations on data read in from text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

As the title side, I am trying to create small programs to do simple calculations on data read in from text files. But I don't know how to turn the elements from the text file into integers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
enter code heredef main():
f = input('enter the file name')
# this line open the file and reads the content f + '.txt' is required
getinfo = open(f +'.txt','r')
content = getinfo.read()
num = []

print('here are the number in your file',  num)
getinfo.close()
```

main ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your .txt file is in this format,

```
1
2
3
4
```

Then you can use the `split` function on `content` like this:

```
f = input('enter the file name')
# this line open the file and reads the content f + '.txt' is required
getinfo = open(f +'.txt','r')
content = getinfo.read()
num = content.split("\n") # Splits the content by every new line

print('here are the number in your file',  num)
getinfo.close()
```

If you need everything in `num` to be of type `int` then you can do a for loop to do that like this

```
f = input('enter the file name')
# this line open the file and reads the content f + '.txt' is required
getinfo = open(f +'.txt','r')
content = getinfo.read()
num = content.split("\n") # Splits the content by every new line

for i in range(len(num)):
   num[i] = int(num[i])

print('here are the number in your file',  num)
getinfo.close()
```

One thing you need to be careful of, however, is to make sure that your text file doesn't contain any characters instead of numbers, otherwise python will try to convert something like "c" to an integer which will cause an error.

Comment: that work! thank you so much! one more question if the text file has more than one number on the same line how would I separate them into integers?

Comment: If they're separated by spaces like `1 2 3 4` then you can do `num.split(" ")` to split by the space character. Here is the link for more information about the split function: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Comment: where do i place the num.split(" ")?